# How Can I stop mp3 player on menu

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I create an items on menu to play mp3. But It couldnt stop. How could I stop mediaplayer when I click "stop" button. I want that clicking stop button must be stopp all playing mp3 on menu.
thanks...

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Toolbar mToolbar;
ImageView mFlower;
TextView mDescription,mBaslik;
Button fab;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MP3  --->");
   }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon2);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    if (id == R.id.stop) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();

        mediaPlayer.release();
       // mediaPlayer.onDestroy();
    }
    if (id == R.id.fav) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon2);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    if (id == R.id.yor) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon3);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    if (id == R.id.asd) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon1);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: obviously by using `MediaPlayer.stop()` **on the same instance of MediaPlayer  object which is playing** (not with newly created)

Comment: }
        if (id == R.id.stop) {


            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }   I tried like this it didnt work also? how can I set my stop button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mp;
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout./////Your activity layout////);


        if(mp != null){
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.stop();
            }
        }

        try {
            descriptor = getAssets().openFd("////the name of your song.mp3////");            // song should be in assets folder
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        audioPlayer();
    }



public void audioPlayer() {
        //set up MediaPlayer

        mp = new MediaPlayer();


        try {

            mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());

            descriptor.close();

            mp.prepare();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



public void OnPlayPressed(View view){


        if(mp.isPlaying()){

            mp.pause();   

        }else{


            mp.start();           

        }


    }




    public void OnStopPressed(View view){



        mp.stop();

        try {
            descriptor = getAssets().openFd("////the name of your song.mp3////");         // song should be in assets folder
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        audioPlayer();

    }
```

Create 2 buttons, 1 for start/pause and one for stop. "OnPlayPressed" is the listener for the first button and "OnStopPressed" is the listener for the second button.

Feel free to mess with this code as long as you get the logic behind it.

Edit: In onStopPressed i reinitialise the descriptor so that you could once again press the "play" button and play your song again. This is not necessary though. You could just write "mp.stop();".

Comment: hi I edit my question it is all my activity. could you look that thanks.

Comment: Hi. Use my code as is but remove 'OnPlayPressed' and 'OnStopPressed' and instead use your ' onOptionsItemSelected' but inside 'if (id == R.id.stop)' write 'mp.stop();'

Comment: Alternatively use your initial code but in cases 'id == R.id.action_settings', 'id == R.id.fav','id == R.id.yor','id == R.id.asd' change 'MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon2);'  to 'mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon2);'

That is your rel issue here. You are creating a new player everytime. Also it would't hurt to stop the player everytime before creating it again.

Comment: Needless to say, don't write '.create(this,R.raw.fon2)' in EVERY case. Write the correct one for each case.

Comment: very thanks I nearly solve it there is a little bug. when I click second mp3 button instead of stop button, after that mp3 never stop. but when ı click mp3 button then click stop button everything is ok. How could I resolve this bug?

Comment: As i said before , when you click another button, first write "mediaPlayer.stop();" and then "create" and "start".

Comment: sorry I am newbie but this time it gives an error when I set the codes like below:  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon1);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

Comment: Change "mediaPlayer.stop();" to "if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){mediaPlayer.stop();}"

Comment: same error again, when I click three mp3 without stop button. afterthat stop button close only one mp3 so other two mp3 go on playing not stop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the MediaPlayer object outside the method like this

```java
MediaPlayer mediaplayer;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.foni) {

        //MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon2);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon2);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    if (id == R.id.stop) {

        //MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    if (id == R.id.fonb) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon1);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    if (id == R.id.fonu) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fon3);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: it gives an error red flag to this:   if (id == R.id.stop) {

           mediaPlayer.stop();
        }

Comment: You can use mediaPlayer=code not everytime MediaPlayer mediaPlayer.

Comment: hi I edit my question it is all my activity. could you look that thanks.

Comment: does it work in that way, Doesnt know what the 3 last id do, i dont how they work